# How to use Typescript object spread operator to add optional properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a property to an object, only if it has been defined:

```js
const b = true;
const a = { ...(b !== undefined ? { b }: null  ) };
```

I was expecting the type of `a` to be:

```
const a: {
    b?: boolean;
}
```

Instead, the type of `a` is:

```
const a: {
    b?: boolean | undefined;
}
```

Using TypeScript 4.8.2

Comment: The type `{b?: boolean}` and `{b?: boolean | undefined}` are identical types unless you enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), which often has undesirable side effects.

Comment: What I'd like is for this type narrowing to happen specifically here, without having to use the compiler option globally (which is causing a lot of other issues like you mentioned)

Comment: With that option off, there is literally no difference between `{x?: X}` and `{x?: X | undefined}`; they are the same type.  You can write `type Foo = {b?: boolean}` and when you inspect it with IntelliSense it will say `type Foo = {b?: boolean | undefined}`.  That compiler setting is the only way to say "sometimes it is wrong to assign `undefined` to an optional property"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this behavior you will need to enable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` in your compiler options:

```
const b = true;
const a = { ...(b !== undefined ? { b }: null  ) };
//   ^? { b?: boolean }
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wer8EN)

Comment: Maybe provide [the handbook doc link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes)?